# Increase and decrease in filter value not working properly in Camanjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, camanjs

I'm using Camanjs for image filtering, I have slider for increasing brightness. Everything works fine when I increase the value to slider which in turns increases the brightness, but now if I decrease the value back to 0, although it decreases the brightness but doesn't return the original image like before increasing the brightness.

eg:

Brightness -> 40 -> Displays image with increased Brightness

Brightness reduced back to zero

```
Brightness -> 0 -> Should display the image with zero brightness.
```

Similarly -> if I have applied blur and then contrast and then remove blur and contrast , i should get original image back.

It should work similar to : http://camanjs.com/examples/

My code:

```
slidderChangeHandler = (event, element) => {
    event.persist();
    let adjust = [...this.state.adjust];
    adjust.map(el => {
      if (el.name === element.name) {
        el.range = event.target.value;
      }
    });
    this.setState({ adjust: adjust }, () => {
      let imgId = null;
      if (
        $(this.props.selected)
          .attr("id")
          .indexOf("text") > -1
      ) {
        imgId =
          "#" +
          $(this.props.selected)
            .children()
            .attr("id");
      } else {
        imgId = "#" + $(this.props.selected).attr("id");
      }
      window.caman(imgId, function() {
        this[element.name](parseFloat(event.target.value)).render()
      });
    });
  };
```

I have tried using **this.revert(true)** before applying filter but that reset the canvas and previous filter are lost.
Can anyone help me out here!!

Comment: post html and javascript in question.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh I have updated the question, it should work similar to http://camanjs.com/examples/

Comment: Can you share codesandbox?